# Return Passport related - Washington DC French Embassy Visa Question

Tags: passports, france, schengen-visas, washington-dc

I have my Visa appointment at the French Embassy (Washington DC). 
I'm travelling from Pennsylvania for the appointment. 
I would like the embassy to return my passport to me via courier. It's not very clear if the embassy sends out the passport via courier. Please note this is not the VFS center. It's the French Embassy in Washington DC at Vermont Avenue. Does anybody have any experience with passport return from the French embassy via courier ?  Which courier service & company is approved ?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. The office at 1025 Vermont Ave NW is indeed VFS Global—the consular office for the embassy is on the grounds of the embassy itself on Reservoir Road, but it seems they have outsourced visa processing since April. I would suggest you contact VFS Global directly.

Comment: To add to what @choster said: the French embassy is on Reservoir Road west of Georgetown, which is quite far from Vermont Ave. and difficult to get to unless you have a car. Make sure you know which one you're going to before you set out!

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the appointment location is 1025 Vermont Avenue. VFS said, they will charge $35 for returning the passport. I think that's pricey. Can buy the return envelope from UPS or USPS or FedEx ? Which one is acceptable. It will be much cheaper for me than buying from VFS.

Comment: $35 is a reasonable cost for trackable shipping. You could save $20 by bringing them another envelope but a) they won't like it because it's different from what they usually do, and b) there's a much greater chance the envelope or label will be mislaid or lost at VFS before it even gets to the carrier. I wouldn't take that chance. YMMV.

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't concern myself with saving a couple dollars when the safety of my passport was at stake.

Comment: I'm done with the appointment on Aug 1. I hope to get my passport soon.